# Does Metal Gear Solid Master Collection let the player know Meryl's codec code anywhere in the downloaded game?

Tags: nintendo-switch, metal-gear-solid

So I'm playing Metal Gear Solid 1 on my Switch. I was quite surprised to see that Kenneth Baker still tells you to search for The Female Prisoner's codec frequency on the CD case given that other lines are updated for the Switch controls, I figured this would be updated to give you the actual codec code.

Back in 1999 this was a really cool (or gimmicky) bit of immersion that might have helped to reduce piracy before the age of the internet. Now in 2023, most players won't have a CD case but can Google the question really easily. It's not hard to find Meryl's codec code, but I'm curious to find if Konami actually went through the effort of keeping the immersion or just said "Screw it, let them Google it"

I checked the Metal Gear Solid master page on the Switch store (as that's probably the closest analog to a CD case), thinking maybe one of the product images has the codec code, but no, no such luck. I know when I downloaded the collection that there was a bonus "game" in my Switch library that might have it, but that would require me to close the game and open the bonus info. Same thing for if there is a "manual" at the title screen, neither of which are very useful. Inconvenience aside, is this information available in the downloaded data anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFpVPHs90Sw) where someone tried to debunk a comment from a viewer saying you can equip the MO Disc and call Campbell.  After doing so, Meryl's frequency gets added.

The video maker wasn't sure if they needed to check the MO Disc multiple times or not, but it does seem to eventually add the frequency.